# Automate the Boring Stuff: Phone and Email Address Extractor (error, copied from example)

Tags: regex, python-3.x

The code below is verbatim to the project example in the book, unless there is a mistake. When I copy some code to the clipboard and then run the program in the IDLE the shell says the below. Please help me troubleshoot.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python3/phoneAndEmail.py", line 23, in <module>
    )''', re.VERBOSE)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "C:\Users\Tyler\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 766, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0 (line 1, column 1)
```

```
#! python3
# phoneAndEmail.py - Finds phone numbers and email addresses on the 
#clipboard.

import pyperclip, re


# Create phone regex
phoneRegex = re.compile(r'''(
   (\d{3}|\(\d{3}\))?                 # area code
   (\s|-|\.)?                         # separator
   (\d{3})                            # 3 digits
   (\s|-|\.)?                         # separator
   (\d{4})                            # 4 digits
   (\s*(ext|x|ext.)\s*(\d{2,5}))?     # ext
   )''', re.VERBOSE)

# Create email regex
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
   [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+                  # username
   @                                  # @
   [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+                     # domain name
   (\.[a-zA-Z]{2-4}                   # dot something
   )''', re.VERBOSE) 

# Find matches in clipboard text.
text = str(pyperclip.paste())
matches = []

for groups in phoneRegex.findall(text):
   phoneNum = '-'.join([groups[1],groups[3], groups[5]])
   if groups[8] != '':
      phoneNum += ' x' + groups[8]
   matches.append(phoneNum)

for groups in emailRegex.findall(text):
   matches.append(groups[0])

#Copy results to clipboard
if len(matches) > 0:
   pyperclip.copy('\n'.join(matches))
   print('Copied to Clipboard:')
   print('\n'.join(matches))
else:
   print('No phone numbers or emails found.')
```

Comment: In your `emailRegex` you have two `(` but only one `)`

Answer (score 2):

Well look at the error:

> sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 0 (line 1, column 1)

```
emailRegex = re.compile(r'''(
   [a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+                  # username
   @                                  # @
   [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+                     # domain name
   (\.[a-zA-Z]{2-4}                   # dot something

)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

That means you are missing a `)`, which you are. There are two `(` but only one `)`

Comment: Wow, that was simple. I was confused by the wall of text the error provided. Thank you

Comment: Usually the problem is at the very end of the stack trace

Comment: @mccluret If it helped, plpease amrk as correct answer :)